# How to force select a newer version of androideabi?

Tags: android-ndk

When I build my code, I see that `$(NDK)\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6` is being used although I have `$(NDK)\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.8` available on my machine.

My understanding is that one should always use the latest androideabi so that the latest gcc compiler can be used. I am wondering why `ndk-build` is picking up an older version.

Here is my Application.mk for your reference:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a 
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++11
```

The value for`APP_PLATFORM`needs to be android-16 so that we can support Android OS version 4.1 and above. I wonder if androideabi is tied to`APP_PLATFORM`value.

Comment: Using NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION is the right answer by Chris Stratton and was already marked so. Dan needs to do a bit more homework.

Comment: Answer or not, it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the ABI, but rather the toolchain version.

You can control this in your Android.mk

From the documentation thereof:

> NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION
>
> Define this variable to either 4.6, 4.7 or 4.8 to select version of the GCC compiler. 4.6 is the default